# How do I find out what was accessed on my computer while it was confiscated?

Tags: windows-7

How do I know what they found or viewed?

Comment: Confiscated by who? Makes a big difference.

Comment: +1, Surprised no one has up voted this yet, it is a great question.

Answer (score 13):

If they did it the forensically correct way, then there is NO WAY to determine what was examined.  The correct way would have been for the forensic tech to pull the hard drive out, clone it, return your hard drive to the machine and then examine the clone image.  There will be no traces whatsoever on your drive since it was never booted.  They will work strictly from the clone image and you should consider everything on the hard drive as having been compromised and you also should be aware they may have retained the image or parts of the image.  Hope you didn't have anything on there you will regret.

Comment: Indeed, you must assume they have seen everything. (Possibly including files you had deleted.) Just consider yourself lucky that they returned the system...

Comment: Another reason for whole disc encryption using Trucrypt.

Comment: As for the TrueCrypt, yes, it should help. But if the attacker is that dedicated, they may also plant a modified TrueCrypt bootloader that will save the entered password, then send it to their server. If they have time to disassemble your laptop, they may even plant a hardware keylogger. Be paranoid, be very paranoid

Comment: No encryption is full proof, it would only be a matter of time before a good hacker bruteforced his way through any hard disk encryption.

Comment: @typoknig : Pure bruteforce on a well implemented strong encryption would take years though. However, if there's weakness found later, the attack could made in shorter time period. As for now, I believe keylogging, hardware and or software, would be easier

Comment: @Martheen Cahya Paulo I agree it could take years, but it really depends on the encryption level.  TrueCrypt allows up to 256 bit encryption I believe, which would take a very long time (years) to decrypt, but the encryption < 128 bit might only take weeks to months (basing this off of my experience with the AES encryption used in WiFi networks).

Comment: Wow, just weeks? Thanks for the info, guess that triple encryption in TrueCrypt isn't too paranoid after all

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo: Yay! Hardware has been compromised, how fix? :D

Comment: A comment about encryption - please remember that in some countries you can be compelled to give the key over upon official request. If you were to use Truecrypt, consider the plausible deniability feature. Still you have to remeber ALL encryption can be broken - look at the recent crack on WPA using Amazon Ec2 as an example.

Comment: I should have mentioned you can't trust your system anymore.  Dependent on the technical capability of whomever you are worried about, consider they mave have installed hardware keyloggers inside the system, software backdoors or keyloggers into the OS and for the seriously worried, buried something into your BIOS.  You may want to start looking into sterilizing the system - how much depends on how much you are worried.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a script to recursively sort files on the system by last access time. However, with all of the activity constantly going on in the file system such as indexing, it is near impossible to determine exactly what they've looked at.

Comment: *Is* or *isn't* near impossible?

Comment: *Is* near impossible. My double negatives get the best of me sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to view the time your files were last accessed, as far as I know:

1. Download the search tool Everything: http://www.voidtools.com/
2. Install it and run the program, and wait for it to index your disk (should take less than a minute)
3. Richt-click on the column headers (where it says "date modified"), and enable "Last accessed"
4. Now search for something random, like `windows`
5. Click on the new column header "Last accessed" to sort search results, so that latest are on top
6. Delete your old search, and search for `*.*`. This will take a long time, especially if this is the first time you use Everything; it could be up to 10 minutes, I don't know how long: that depends on your PC; just keep waiting, it took me 3 minutes on this old-ish PC
7. Now you have a list of all the files on your PC, listed by the time they were last accessed, with dates and times.

Note that Windows also accesses some files when the PC is on without external output, so it you can't be sure it was they who accessed a file.